# Choose which partition to format when installing Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, partitioning

When installing Windows 8 I got this error message:

```
Windows cannot be installed to this hard disk space. 
Windows must be installed to a partition formatted as NTFS.  

Windows cannot be installed to this hard disk space. 
The partition is of an unrecognized type.
```

I know I got this because I've got Ubuntu on it, but I really want to be sure before I mess up my computer. Do I need to format partition 2 or do I need to do something else? These are the partitions I have:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any data left on your hard drive? If so, then be **absolutely sure** to create a backup!

---

1. **Delete that partition**

   That's the only option you have, according to your screenshot.
2. **Create a new partition**

   A new list item called "Unallocated space" should appear. Click "New" and create a new partition. You should choose about 25 GB minimum space.
3. **Format**

   Select the created partition and hit "Format".

   As far as I can remember, this step is not absolutely necessary since Windows will automatically perform it if you haven't done yourself.

Comment: Won't I lose any partitions?

Comment: @sofboy You will lose partition #2. On which partition is Ubuntu installed? Do you want to overwrite the whole hard disk?

Comment: Yes,but the size of mine memory(923GB) will stay?:p

Comment: @sofboy The disk space of your hard drive will never change. If you directly follow my steps, the partition size will stay the same (freeing 923 GB --> unallocated state --> creating new parition 923 GB).